# String Concatenation in Ruta

Tags: nlp, text-mining, uima, ruta

does somebody know what is wrong with my String Concatenation in Ruta?

```
    FOREACH (d) IngredientConcept{} {
    d{->CREATE(Entity, "label"="Drug", "value"= d.conceptID + "_" + d.dictCanon)};
    }
```

Caused by: org.apache.uima.ruta.extensions.RutaParseRuntimeException: Error in Anonymous, line 28, "+": expected RPAREN, but found PLUS

Thanks for your help.
Philipp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this:
    "value"= "" + d.conceptID + "_" + d.dictCanon

Comment: Yes, this works. It's not quite self-explanatory that you have to put quotation marks at the beginning of a string concatentation. That may be useful to be fixed in a future Ruta version. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The leading quotes are required for UIMA Ruta 2.7.0 (at least).